# SMTP connection with node

Tags: node.js, sockets, email, smtp, gmail

I'm trying to connect my client to a gmail smtp server without using specific node-smtp libs ( i want to understand how sockets and smtp both work ), but after setting a connection to a server i get no response whatever i write to a socket.
This is a part of my code:

```
var options = {
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    username: 'mylogin@gmail.com',
    password: 'mypass',
    port: 25
    },
    net = require('net');

exports.addEmail = function(req, res) {

    var client = net.connect(options.port, options.host, function() {
        console.log('CONNECTED TO: ' + options.host + ':' + options.port);
        //i can write to a socket anything, still no response
        client.write('HELO smtp.gmail.com');
    });

    client.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('DATA: ' + data);
    });

    client.on('error', function(err) { console.log(err );})

    client.on('close', function() {
        console.log('Connection closed');
    });
}
```

What i get in console is: 
  CONNECTED TO: smtp.gmail.com:25
  DATA: 220 mx.google.com ESMTP n7sm5406410lae.47 - gsmtp

That's all - no errors, no 5xx or 4xx responses, only 220 after establishing a connection and i don't understand why it happesns I will highly appreciate your help.

Comment: wrong port! use `465` and `ssl: true`, instead of `25`. And also, WHAT YOU WANT TO DO WITH THIS CODE??

Comment: If you want to learn how SMTP works first read and understand the relevant standard [RFC2821](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt) and then start coding. This is better than trying some writes which do not conform to the standard and then wondering why it does not work. Some hint: don't forget to send the line ends.

Comment: @Ravi it's just a piece of code which i want to send any data (even incorrect) to a smtp server and to get any response. After i figure out how to do it i'll try to send correct email data to the server. How can i enable ssl?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thank you very much for your comment - server didn't answer because i didn't put line end in my message.

Comment: @AndreiHrabouski there are some prebuilt modules, which you can use in your app. e.g [Node Mailer](https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer) , must read it's documentation before use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a reference for future readers, you need to add a carriage return (\r) and newline (\n) character at the end of your commands:

```
client.write('HELO smtp.gmail.com\r\n');
```

Comment: I assume you are trying to ping the email address from your code. In order to achieve this we have a couple of more commands. How are you processing the responses? I am struggling in processing the last response which shows if the server is accepting messages or not.