# SMTP Troubleshoot

Tags: javascript, node.js, gmail

I started implementing a mail project on Node.js. Now I'm trying to figure out how to send a message to another mailbox, do I understand correctly that:

1. port 25 is used for connection between different mail agents, that is, if I want to send a message from telnet (or from my mail) to gmail, then I should use this port? (Is this called sending?)
2. Port 587 is used if I want to send messages from my mail (for example Gmail), that is, I have to go through to send a message? (This is called retransement? When does the letter go between the accounts of one postal agent)
3. on port 25 do I need to use the mx record to connect to other mail?

UPT: if you are looking for answers, i recommend you check this link:
https://serverfault.com/questions/1045480/e-mail-transmission-example

Comment: Port 25 is without encryption and no longer supported by most mail hosts. Port 587 is where you'll reach your own SMTP (outgoing mail) server. I.e. if you want to send from your gmail address, you need to connect to `smtp.gmail.com:587` using TLS encryption, log in using your gmail credentials, then provide a recipient, subject, body etc. Your node program will send all this to the SMTP server, which in turn will send the mail to the recipient's ingoing mail server

Comment: I'd use [nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com/about/#example), unless your goal is to learn how to communicate with an SMTP server?

Comment: I want to send a message from my own smtp, where i will be writing EHLO gmail, STARTTLS, DATA etc, so the variant with smtp.gmail.com: 587 does not suit me.

Comment: That's how an SMTP server communicates though, so you have to make a connection to smtp.gmail.com:587 then send these commands. Again, *only* if you want to actually learn how to do that. You don't need any of that to send a mail with node.

Comment: Also, dupe: [SMTP connection with node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26211431/smtp-connection-with-node)

Comment: If I want to send a message on behalf of my google account, then I use smtp.gmail.com (in this case I need to go through authorization or another login), and if I want to send to google from my smtp, then I need to access the record mx?

Comment: You have your own SMTP server?

Comment: Yes, i made smtp on tcp port, which supports requests on commands like Helo, Data, Rset (all commands have been discribed in RFC 2821) and i made data entry into an array like recipient, sender, date so that i can display it on the vue page. I hosted on AWS EC2, but only then I found out that port 25 was closed initially, I applied and they answered no. Now I will run the server on Heroku hosting. I bought a domain, set up DKIM DMARK SPF records. Am I on the right track at all?

Comment: Not sure if creating your own SMTP server is the way to go here. Let me put it this way: if you are able to do that, you don't need to ask questions on stack overflow. You already are an expert programmer.